# Exothermic temperature rise on NaOH + Methanol

Tags: enthalpy, heat

When mixing NaOH (w/w 0.05%) with methanol, there is an increase of temperature around 20 C

I wonder if we keep this ratio in large amount of methanol, will there be any spike in temperature increase or it will remain constant?

I am not quite good at math but i assume there must be constant?

But upon quick search, this guy

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Wn-kD5YzqA

At 2:56 mentioning that:

> The dissolution reaction is exothermic, meaning it produces off heat. At larger scale it can
> even produce dangerously high levels of heat,
> getting to above the point of boiling for methanol, which is 140 F

So is he correct or i do? thank you in advance

Comment: There would be increase even without NaOH, similarly as with water + ethanol. // Assuming you mix 0.05% w/w water solution of NaOH with methanol.

Comment: It's not constant at all, depending on many factors. I wager you're doing it wrong to let it heat up so much with so small concentration.